# Typescript type for a loaded image

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a simple function which draws an image to a canvas:

```
function drawImage(image: HTMLImageElement, context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
  context.drawImage(image);
}
```

The problem here is that I expect the consumer of this function to implement it like:

```
const image = new Image();
image.onload = () => drawImage(image, context);
image.src = "...";
```

How do I force typescript to handle the image argument to be a loaded image?

Something like this is not working:

```
type LoadedImage = HTMLImageElement & {
  loading: false;
  complete: true;
}
```

Comment: Unless you use a type assertion anyway, you would need some kind of runtime check like `if(image.complete && !image.loading)`, and if you write that check anywhere in the code where you know the image is already loaded, the only sensible thing to do if the check fails is to throw an exception. So you might as well check and throw in the `drawImage` function, in which case the problem is moot.

Comment: Alternatively you could write a helper function with an `asserts image is LoadedImage` return type, which is still a type assertion but you can enforce it with a runtime check if you want.

Comment: Better approach is to have Parameter Decorators : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators